# MongoDB/mongoose - Nested documents are not being saved

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got 4 models, `Grid`, `Container`, `Row` and `Column`. I need to init a `Grid` with the rest of the 3 models nested in it.

The problem I'm having is that references to `Container`, `Row` and `Column` are created (`ObjectId`s), but the documents themselves aren't saved. Only the `Grid` document is saved.

I would expect it to save the rest of the models to their respective collections as well...

What am I missing?

Here are my models/schemas:

```
const GridSchema = new Schema({
  container: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Container', required: true}
});

const ContainerSchema = new Schema({
  rows: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Row'}]
});

const RowSchema = new Schema({
  columns: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Column'}]
});

const ColumnSchema = new Schema({
  modules: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Module'}]
});

const Grid = mongoose.model('Grid', GridSchema);
const Container = mongoose.model('Container', ContainerSchema);
const Row = mongoose.model('Row', RowSchema);
const Column = mongoose.model('Column', ColumnSchema);
```

Here's how I init my grid and saving it:

```
  const grid = new Grid({
    container: new Container({
      rows: [
        new Row({
          column: [
            new Column({
              modules: []
            })
          ]
        })
      ]
    })
  });

  grid.save((err, grid) => {
     console.log(err, grid); // No error is thrown
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse the nested documents will not be saved, as you are not calling their `.save()` calls.

Also instead of creating then like this, create then individually, and then use their references or variables to work with. that'll make your work easier and cleaner.

**Edit:** to specify how to make multiple save at once.

You can do it like this:

```
column = new Column({
    modules: []
});
row = new Row({
    column: [column._id]
});
container = new Container({
    rows: [row._id]
});
grid = new Grid({
    container
});
Promise.all([column.save(), row.save(), container.save(), grid.save()]).then((docs) => {
    //all the docs are conatined in docs, this is success case, i.e. all document gets saved
    console.log(docs);
}).catch((error) => {
    // handle error here, none of the documents gets saved
    // if saving of anyone of the documents fails, it all gets failed
});
```

Promise.all() is very useful for saving multiple documents like this. As Mongodb has no feature to support transactions.

And my apologies for late reply.

Comment: But what if saving one of them fails? How do you handle that? If one fails then the others shouldn't be saved.

Comment: @chrillewoodz please check and tell if the edited part helps you answer your question.